# Query to the get the Max value using Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of Users:

```
|Username|UserType|
|John    |A       |
|Mary    |A       |
|Anna    |B       |
```

and UserPoints

```
|UserType|MinPoints|Level  |
|A       |100      |Bronze |
|A       |200      |Silver |
|A       |300      |Gold   |
|B       |500      |Bronze |
```

and Useraddress

```
|UserType|Address
|A       |Address1
|B       |Address2
```

I am looking for a query to get the max value of MinPoints column.

I want the result without using Group by clause.
I tried the below

```
Select UserType,UA.Address
,(Select max(MinPoints) from Users T1 WHERE T1.Usertype=U.Usertype)MinPoints from Users U
Left Join UserAddress UA on UA.UserType=U.UserType
```

```
Select UserType,UA.Address,MinPoints 
from Users U
Left Join UserAddress UA on UA.UserType=U.UserType
Left Join (Select UserType,max(MinPoints) from Users T1 Group by UserType) x ON X.Usertype=U.Usertype
```

For the above queries I got the same result.
But what I want is which is query is better keeping in view the performance.

Please suggesst

Comment: Neither - they don't make much sense and I'm surprised they run. `MinPoints` is not a column in Users. If you want to retrieve `MAX(MinPoints)` per user type and address, use `SELECT p.UserType,a.Address, Max(MinPoints) From UserPoints p inner Join UserAddress a on on p.UserType=a.UserType GROUP BY p.UserType,a.Address`

Comment: How do you distinguish between John's `UserPoints` and Mary's `UserPoints`?

Answer (score 0):

This will return all user data for the user or users whose `MinPoints` are equal to the maximum value of `MinPoints`. With the sample data, `JOIN` will work, but you may need them to be `LEFT JOIN`s.

```
SELECT
  u.UserName,
  ua.Address,
  up.MinPoints AS MaxOfMinPoints
FROM
  UserPoints AS up
  JOIN
  Users AS u
    ON u.UserType = up.UserType
  JOIN
  UserAddress AS ua
    ON ua.UserType = up.UserType
WHERE
  up.MinPoints = (SELECT MAX(s.MinPoints) FROM UserPoints AS s)
```

Comment: I am missing UserType A with this result. I want both the usertypes with highest points in each.

Comment: Distinct User types is to be selected and accordingly highest points.

Comment: Then it should say that in the question. Take a look at [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).